# How can I overcome this getApplicationContext Error

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to make a  login app using a youtube tutorial but I am getting this error

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(usersData.getImageURL()).into(imageView);
```

the error is at **`getApplicationContext`** so how can I overcome this please

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: show your full code.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In Context, if you are in Activity.

```
Glide.with(this).load(usersData.getImageURL()).into(imageView);
```

if you are in Fragment

```
Glide.with(fragment).load(usersData.getImageURL()).into(imageView);
```